# Chrome grey Text is unreadable

Tags: google-chrome

Yesterday my Chrome text color (for some sites, including stackoverflow) changed to an unreadable light grey color. I do not have any extensions installed. I tried resetting the Chrome Settings. I have tried adding a couple of extensions to improve the text color, but they do not help. Any suggestions?  Screenshots at https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTiE5.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

For others' information .... what I had done was install a new font for a completely unrelated task (image logo editing under GIMP).  The new font clashed with (replaced?) a font being used by many websites, and hence made my browser visibility "horrible".  I deleted the newly installed font, and hey presto! - back to much better browsing the web.  This may be of some use to others?